# Running parallel tests in Azure Devops

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ui-automation, parallel-testing

I have selenium tests developed on java. Since devs are using Azure Devops, we are asked to use it for the test pipelines. We have configured one project on one pipeline. Classic pipelines are used, however I am happy to use Yaml if there is any solution that can I use to achieve this

One of the pipeline has around 900 scenarios that takes around 14 hours to execute. I have 1 agent pool with 2 agents configured to run 2 different pipelines in parallel. All this is configured to run on self hosted server on premise.

However I am unable to divide the 900 scenarios to run in parallel on 2 different agents. Is it possible?

I tried to add agent job to run in parallel but both jobs execute the same scenarios in parallel.

[image]

Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of task are you using to run your tests? Are you using YAML or classic pipelines? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: thanks for replying. its classic pipeline. I tried to add another job to agent use the same tasks and config as in screenshot attached. Just FYI we do have subscription for parallel jobs

Comment: OK so your question should be, "how do I run tests in parallel with Maven?". I think you can do limited parallelisation with Maven (running tests in parallel on a single agent) but if you want to utilise multiple agents then you'll need to package up your tests in to  jar files and run them using another test runner.

Comment: I can use multiple agent to run multiple pipelines at a same time as of now however I need to slice up the pipeline to divide the scenarios on multiple agents or multiple jobs